# How can I pull data from Laravel after a user has authenticated via OAuth in mobile app?

Tags: php, angularjs, api, laravel, oauth

I created a web app in Laravel in which users login using social networks via OAuth. Once authenticated, they can interact with the website and pull respective data from MySQL.

Now I'm building a mobile app, this app is hybrid (meaning I'm building it with HTML, CSS, JS using AngularJS). I want users to login using social networks via Oauth on the mobile app and then I want them to be able to pull data from my Laravel website via an API.

How do I authenticate a user in my laravel site via an API, and how can I make sure that I properly validate them before I return data?

Comment: Well, where do you store your user's data? I mean you authenticate them via 3rd party login, but where do you store your user's data? If you store your user's data somerwhere, then maybe try to establish a connection to the same database. Or try to link your angular app accounts with you laravel app accounts.